# node - deploying app to heroku with git

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

[image][image]I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and I keep getting this error message saying that it "failed to detect app matching ......." and the push was rejected.  I followed the way it said on the heroku website and I keep getting stuck on only that git push heroku master part I have tried doing some research I couldn't find a solution.   [image]

```
{
  "name": "home-automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "johnny-five": "^0.11.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

**Server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var express = require("express");

var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board({port:"COM4"});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"))

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("New User Connected")
    board.on("ready", function(){
        socket.on("turnLightOn", function(data){
            var led = new five.Led({
                pin:"13"
            });
            if(data.status){
                led.on();
            }else{
                led.off();
            }
        })
    })
});

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 3000")
});
```

**index.js**

```
var socket = io();

$("#toggle-light").on("click", function(){
    $("#led").toggle();
    if($("#led").css("display") == "none"){
        var status = false
    }else{
        var status = true
    }
    socket.emit("turnLightOn", {
        status
    })
})
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Automation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Automation</h1>
        <button id="toggle-light">Toggle Light</button>
        <div id="led" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;"></div>

        <p id="moistureLevel"></p>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that a package.json file isn't checked into the root of your git project, so Heroku is detecting that it isn't a Node.js app. You can see this locally:

```
git show master:package.json
```

To fix it, you'll want to be sure there is a package.json in the root of your project (where there is also a .git directory), and add it to git:

```
git add package.json
git commit -m 'track package.json'
```

The phrasing ('failed to detect set buildpack') could be improved. It should probably say 'failed to detect Node.js app'. When the buildpack's "detect" script is run (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/detect), it looks for a package.json file to verify that there's a node app available to build.

Comment: That did help with deploying to heroku and but I get an application error which referred me to my build log (build log too long for comment)

Comment: maybe you can show me a liitle bit of it like " Error: Cannot find module bla bla bla" maybe you forgot some module to add to package.json

Comment: I added some pictures above

Comment: i dont see any error message where is the error then it looks like the error doesnt come from the build but it comes from your script itself because if error is from the build the last line that say "http:blablabla has deployed to heroku" is not gonna be there

Comment: Well it works perfectly fine when I see it on local host.  Could it possibly be my package.json file?Added above.

Comment: do you try to use another port? because the only usable port in heroku is environtment variables called "process.env.PORT" there is no error because of module than maybe its something in your code not the package.json one

Comment: I updated above so you can see all my code, but as mentioned before, the code works on local host on port 3000 but I just have problems when it comes to heroku

Comment: i think its because your arduino doesnt connect to the heroku the localhost can work because computer can find your device port but heroku cant do it because heroku is in the cloud somewhere in unknown city maybe you can use [zetta](http://www.zettajs.org/)  which is a good IoT layer that sits on top of hardware. Zett's job is to get the data from an agent like yours to and from a cloud location (like Heroku). It has really great dashboards and a great REST API. but i never use it im sorry coz i dont have arduino this [link](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/issues/910) maybe can help